# htaccess rewrite all but one php file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do i rewrite all files but one "logout.php" 
I've tried this but it just give's me a 404:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
# You may need to uncomment the following line if rewrite fails to work
# RewriteBase must be setup to base URL of your aMember installation without
# domain name
    RewriteBase /amember4
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/logout\.php$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^public public.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^js.php js.php [L]
    RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|csv|html)$ index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: "logout.php"? You are sure?

Comment: yes I'm sure i've just noticed it's set to login I'm updating now!

Comment: Ok, that looks different :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RewriteCond only applies to the next RewriteRule. So you have to repeat it or in this case just move it down before the third RewriteRule :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteBase /amember4
    RewriteRule ^public public.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^js.php js.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^logout.php logout.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/logout\.php$ [NC]
    RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|csv|html)$ index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @vimes1984 is your file logout.php in the amenber4 directory ?

Comment: I've edited my post and added a rule for the logout page

Comment: Ok ! I think the RewriteCond is useless now because we have an individual rule for logout.php with [L] flag, which means don't try to find another rule, just use this.